# list<pair<float,float>> iterating through a list that holds pairs?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

As a part of runtime analysis I've got a small game that after calculating every Frame puts a new element in this list:

```cpp
typedef std::list<std::pair<float, float>> PairList;

PairList Frames; //in pair: index 0 = elapsed time, index 1 = frames
```

The txt file is later used to draw a graph.
I decided to use a list, because while playing I do not need to process data held in the list and I think lists are the fastest containers when it comes to only adding or deleting items. As a next step I want to write the frames in an external txt file.

```cpp
void WriteStats(PairList &pairList)
{
    // open a file in write mode.
    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("afile.dat");

    PairList::iterator itBegin = pairList.begin();
    PairList::iterator itEnd = pairList.end();

    for (auto it = itBegin; it != itEnd; ++it)
    {
        outfile << *it.first << "\t" << *it.second;
    }
    outfile.close();

}
```

With normal lists the pointer to "it" should  return the item right?
Except visual studio says `pair<float, float>*` does not have a member called first
How do I want to do it then, when access via my iterator does not work? Is it because I pass in the reference to the list?

Comment: Output of (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) will be `1\t23\t45\t6` ... may be tricky to parse as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*it.first` is parsed as `*(it.first)`.

You need `(*it).first` or, better yet `it->first`.

Or, even better yet use range for:

```
for (auto& elem : pairList)
{
    float a = elem.first;
}
```

---

> I decided to use a list, because [...] I think lists are the fastest containers when it comes to only adding or deleting items.

The first go-to container should be `std::vector`. In practice it will outperform `std::list` even on algorithms that on paper should be faster on `std::list` because of cache locality. So I would test your theory with a good-ol benchmarking if performance is a concern.

Comment: every option works perfectly, thanks. As a matter of fact I did some testing with lists and vectors. When Adding 1million elements to a vector with the iota() function, it takes up to 86 times longer than adding to a list. Thats quite a small difference though, when you want to calculate every element +1 vectors are more than 6000 times faster.

Comment: @onefriendlyprogrammer Those results look very very suspicious. You should double check your testing methodology.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is one of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  Specifically, the member access operator '.' has higher precedence than indirection '*' so `*it.first` is effectively parsed as...

```
*(it.first)
```

Hence the warning.  Instead use...

```
it->first
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of messing with iterators:

```
void WriteStats(const PairList &pairList)
{
    // open a file in write mode.
    std::ofstream outfile("afile.dat");

    for (const auto &elem : pairList) {
      outfile << elem.first << "\t" << elem.second << '\n';
    }
}
```